# Draw 2D/3D shapes and vector arrows and view at different angles

Tags: windows, open-source

I want to draw physics diagrams, and view the entire figure at different angles.

Is there a simple software for that?

For example if I draw a cuboid, I want to be able to view it at different angles.

[image]

I made this in MS PowerPoint, but I can't rotate it in 3D or view it at different angles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A free CAD type program may be your best option, although the reference to free is not a requirement noted in your question.

One program free for hobbyists is [Fusion 360](https://www.autodesk.com/products/fusion-360/overview), but it's quite complex to learn. There are many YouTube tutorials and commercial video productions to support the program, reducing the challenge of learning such a powerful piece of software.

Another program, also free and somewhat less complex is [Solvespace](http://solvespace.com/index.pl). Both programs work on the premise of creating sketches in a plane, adding constraints (or not) and allowing three dimensional viewing and editing of those sketches.

There are other similar programs but the two referenced above are those in which I have some experience and believe will serve your purposes.

As you do not require many of the complex features of Fusion 360, I suggest that Solvespace will provide for your requirements with the shortest learning curve. Consider to view a few tutorial videos for this program to assist in your decision.